# ReferenceError: $event is not defined

Tags: angularjs

We get an error when using bottomsheet

```
div(flex="15" data-ng-click="showGridBottomSheet(testExecution)" class="link-style")
```

Below is the called function

```
$scope.showGridBottomSheet = function(obj) {

    testexecutionServices.testexeustionObj = obj;
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
        scope: $scope,
        targetEvent: $event,
        preserveScope: true,
        templateUrl: 'testexecutions/testExecutionResult',
        controller: 'testexecutionCtrl'
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {

    }, function() {});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `$event` in your function parameters like this:

```
$scope.showGridBottomSheet = function(obj, $event) {

testexecutionServices.testexeustionObj = obj;
$mdBottomSheet.show({
    scope: $scope,
    targetEvent: $event,
    preserveScope: true,
    templateUrl: 'testexecutions/testExecutionResult',
    controller: 'testexecutionCtrl'
}).then(function(clickedItem) {

}, function() {});
};
```

and in your HTML, pass your `$event` to the function call :

```
div(flex="15" data-ng-click="showGridBottomSheet(testExecution,$event)" class="link-style")
```

If you are not using it set it to `null`.